# Change the picture position for the desktop background in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, desktop-background

I have wrote this code to change the desktop background using the function [SystemParametersInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227580(v=vs.60).aspx) in the Windows API `user32.dll` :

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Declare Auto Function SystemParametersInfo Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal Z As String, ByVal W As Integer) As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            SystemParametersInfo(20, 0, Application.StartupPath & "\Frames\animation" & FrameX & ".png", 1 Or 2)
        Catch ex As Exception : End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

What I need to know if I can change the picture position of that desktop background - the same property when changing the background from the `Control Panel` - as shown below :

---

[image]

**UPDATE :**
I found the right solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989906/how-to-set-wallpaper-style-fill-stretch-according-to-windows-version).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19989906/how-to-set-wallpaper-style-fill-stretch-according-to-windows-version)

Comment: @Youssef13, Thanks, that did work.